# building script tags that load in order and accept variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below instead of using

```
<script src="" ></script
```

I am building the script up. This will enable me to insert client and calc names - i.e. add variables into the src that i am calling. This leads to js errors as scripts are not loaded in at the right time/ order.

here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var client = 'test';
var calc = 'loanCalculator';

var insertScript = function(src){
   var element= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= src;
   element.appendChild(script);
}

var insertScriptContent = function(code){
  var element= document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var script= document.createElement('script');
  script.type= 'text/javascript';
  script.innerHTML  = code;
   element.appendChild(script);
}

    insertScript('http://test.com.au/clients/' + client +'/web/'+calc+'/calculator-lib.js');
    insertScript('http://test.com.au/api/configeditor/213?callback=setupConfig');
    insertScript('http://test.com.au/clients/' + client +'/web/javascripts/c-app.js');

        insertScriptContent('var __loancalculator = null; var calculator = null; var loadTool = function(){ __loancalculator = abcd("abcd.loancalculator"); var container = $(".loan-calculator-app"); container.empty(); calculator = new __loancalculator.LoanCalculatorApp(container); calculator.init(); };');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadTool();
});
</script>
```

is there a way to load the top libraries and then the document .ready actually runs when these are loaded? or is there a better way to add these variables in?

thanks

Comment: First thing add the punctuation ';'  right after `var calc = 'loanCalculator'`

Comment: and where is the definition of `loadTool()` ?

Comment: its on the long line..

Comment: @Dan seeing that you're using jQuery, have a look at [`.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) in combination with [`.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Answer (score 0):

Scripts can only be loaded at the begining of the rendering of the page. So it's not possible to load them when your page already loaded. You can define them normally in the head and then call them in a specific order.

Comment: i am not sure this is exactly true

Comment: Scripts that appear within a SCRIPT element are executed when the document is loaded. For user agents that cannot or will not handle scripts, authors may include alternate content via the NOSCRIPT element. source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.4

Comment: @MarouaGasmi So? That has nothing to do with the question at hand, nor with your statement that script tags cannot be added later on. You're answer is simply wrong, you should delete it.

Comment: He is creating script tags and adding content to them and using a function called inside one of them !!

Comment: Yes that might be the wrong approach, still, it is not correct to say that *Scripts can only be loaded at the begining of the rendering of the page*. You can add script tags, with or without content, with or without a src-attribute, at any time, and the browser will execute the code.